# Jquery .clicked does not function

Tags: jquery, codeigniter

I am trying to add another row in a table(that contains form inputs) when the add button is clicked.

Here is my code:

```
$("#add_ingr").click(function(){
    var row = '<tr>'
                   +'<td>' 
                      +'<?php $data = array('name' => 'ingr_name[]', 'class' => 'ingr_name'); echo form_input($data); ?>'
                   +'</td>'
                   +'<td>'  
                      +'<?php $data = array('name' => 'ingr_amount[]', 'class' => 'amt'); echo form_input($data); ?>'
                   +'</td>'
                   +'<td>'
                      +'<?php $data = array('name' => 'ingr_unit[]', 'class' => 'unit'); echo form_input($data); ?>'
                      +'<span class="remove">X</span>'+'</td>';                                                             
              +'</tr>';

   $("#ingr_table > tbody").append(row);
```

});

Whenever I would click the element with an ID of add_ingr, a new row would successfully be appended on the table but whenever I would click the x text which has the class of remove, this code never gets executed:

```
$("span.remove").click(function() {
alert('clicked');
    $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

I don't know what was wrong with it and I've been trying to find a solution for my problem but unfortunately, I can't have things working.

Can somebody tell me what's wrong with this? I would really appreciate your help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you're looking for [`.parents('tr')`](http://api.jquery.com/parents/).

Comment: @Jared. This problem has been solved. I followed what Vidhu suggested below. Thank for your response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The click handler is not being bound to the element. Either change your code to:

```
$("span.remove").live('click', function() {
    alert('clicked');
    $(this).closest('tr').remove();
});
```

so that it `span.remove` is always bound, or place the bind inside of your other click function:

```
$("#add_ingr").click(function(){
    var row = $('<tr>'
                   +'<td>' 
                      +'<?php $data = array('name' => 'ingr_name[]', 'class' => 'ingr_name'); echo form_input($data); ?>'
                   +'</td>'
                   +'<td>'  
                      +'<?php $data = array('name' => 'ingr_amount[]', 'class' => 'amt'); echo form_input($data); ?>'
                   +'</td>'
                   +'<td>'
                      +'<?php $data = array('name' => 'ingr_unit[]', 'class' => 'unit'); echo form_input($data); ?>'
                      +'<span class="remove">X</span>'+'</td>';                                                             
              +'</tr>');

   $("#ingr_table > tbody").append(row);
   row.find('span.remove').click(function() {
     alert('clicked');
     $(this).closest('tr').remove();
   });
 });
});
```

Also, `.parent()` will select the `<td>` element, so I changed this to `.closest('tr')` which will select the closest table row.

Comment: Hi Vibhu. Thank you very much for your help. I really helped me out. Thank you!